# Laravel, different output when passing variable from controller to js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

As you can see my code below, I have defined a `$test` variable in controller. The problem is, when I passing the variable to js, it became different result.

**Controller**

```
$test = "{name: 'John',color: 'olive',data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],stack: '2014',xAxis: 1}";
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var test = {{$test}}; // result is {name: &#039;John&#039;,color: &#039;olive&#039;,data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],stack: &#039;2014&#039;,xAxis: 1};
</script>
```

**Inspect**

[image]

Comment: You should form array (or object) and pass `json_encoded($formedObject)` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's becouse of the nature of blade {{}}. It's removing some characters. Try using `{!! $test !!}`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#displaying-data

Comment: Update answer with a link

Answer (score 1):

In view

```
var test = {!! $test!!};
```

Double braces is escaping your characters.

Comment: The correct Laravel syntax to not escape is `{!! $test !!}`